# javafx animation with PathTransition is not smooth

Tags: animation, javafx

I am learning javafx.animation. I created an ellipse and a rectangle and make rectangle travel along the border of ellipse . I make this animation repeat indefinitely. The problem is the transition between animation circles is not smooth. That means after the first round of animation finishes, it take a noticeable amount of time for next round of animation to start. This just looks ugly. Is there anyway to make it more smooth?

Thank you in advance.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;

public class TestAnimation extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        //create pane and nodes
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(300, 300, 100, 200);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 80);
        rect.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(ellipse, rect);

        //create animation
        PathTransition path = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(2400), ellipse, rect);
        path.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        //path.setAutoReverse(true);
        path.play();

        //define mouse event
        ellipse.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                path.pause();
            }
        });

        ellipse.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                path.play();
            }
        });

        //set up stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is caused by the Interpolator, that smoothes the start and stop of an animation by accelerating and decelerating the movement. Setting path.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR) should have changed that, but does not for some reason. Maybe someone else can tell both us of why that is :)

Comment: That works fine for me...

Comment: @johnRW that actually works for me. I set the path.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR), now it's perfectly smooth. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnRW I think you should post this as an answer.